# How do I test if an entity’s score = 0?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a hide & seek scoreboard countdown for a friend of mine's hide and seek game. I want to ask how do you use `/execute` to test if an entity’s scoreboard is equal to 0?

I have an armour stand with a score that goes down by 1 every second, so I wanted to make it so that it runs a command when the score equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/execute if` to perform a command if score matches 0 using the following:

```
/execute if score <target> <targetObjective> matches 0
```

Note that if you want the opposite - a command to run when a score does **not** match 0, you would use `/execute unless`, i.e.

```
/execute unless score <target> <targetObjective> matches 0
```

You can read more about `/execute` on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute)